# What's the difference between (Record<string, unkown>) and object type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What's the difference between type Record<string, unkown> and type object?

Implement a generic `DeepReadonly<T>` which make every parameter of an object - and its sub-objects recursively - readonly.

I wrote a type：

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends object ? {readonly:[K in keyof T]:DeepReadonly<T[K]>}:T
```

but it's not correctly.
replaced this `object` width `Record<string,unkown>`, the 'DeepReadonly' worked well.
What's the difference?
Is that `object` could be empty?But the `Record<string,unkown>` must be `{[key:string]:unkown}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type `object` refers to `Reference Type`, it can be an array, function, or object literal.
Record<> only refers to object literal.